# How to return an object from different classes in Java?

Tags: java, return-type

I'm beginner in Java and I need help. I have several classes.

```
public class A{
  private String name = "A";

  public String getClassName(){
   return "A";
 }

  public void editClassName(String name){
   this.name = name;
  }
}

public class B{
  private String name = "B";
  private int counter = 0;

  public String showClassName(){
    return "B";
  }

  public int getCount(){
    return counter;
  }
}
```

Such classes could be more. I also need to have some class witch can return an instance of asked class.

```
public class ClassSelector{
  public static ??? getClassByName(String nameOfClass){
   if(nameOfClass == "A"){ return new A();}
   if(nameOfClass == "B"){ return new B();}
  }
}
```

And here is a code that I want to use to get access to appropriate class:

```
ClassSelector.getClassByName("A").getClassName();
ClassSelector.getClassByName("B").showClassName();
```

I need to have an access to the instance of the class, and each instance can show it's unit methods that class has.

In this situation I don't get which return type I should use in the 'getClassByName' method.
I will very appreciate for help.

Comment: It can only be `Object`, since that's the only common super class of `A` and `B`

Comment: Note that `getClassByName` is misleading, since your method returns an instance of a class. `getInstanceByClassName` would be a better name

Comment: Thank you, Eran. Yes you are right, getInstanceByClassName is better.

Answer (score 7):

I would very much like to offer an alternative architecture if possible! It's not much different to what you have.

Firstly, we'll define some interface.

```
public interface Named {
    String getName();
}
```

Now, this means you can have lots of concrete classes but provided they implement this interface, you'll know (and the Java compiler will know) that they have the `getName` method available to you.

Next, let's update your class to implement this interface.

```
public class A implements Named {
    public String getName() {
        return "A";
    }
}
```

You could do this for classes `B`, `C`... and so on.

Now your method return type can be set to `Named`, that is:

```
public class ClassSelector{
  public static Named getClassByName(String nameOfClass){
   if(nameOfClass.equals("A")){ return new A();}
   if(nameOfClass.equals("B")){ return new B();}
  }
}
```

And you can access the response like so:

```
Named response = ClassSelector.getClassByName("A").getName();
```

Comment: Seems like a builder design pattern or factory may be.

Comment: In the if condition instead of `nameOfClass == "A"` it should be `"A".equals(nameOfClass)`

Comment: Thank you guys for help. It is almost what I need. I see that I made some mistake in the code example which lied to misunderstanding. I will change the code to what I meant.

Comment: @Jack Hi Jack, if this solves your problem, could you please accept the answer? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Christopher, unfortunately no, this is not wnat I need. I made changes in the first post, where add some additional things, which shown better what I searching.

Answer (score 2):

As Eran suggested, it can be only of type Object, because they don't have a common superclass other than Object. If you don't want to work with Object class, you can create a body-less interface and implement it in both(or multiple classes) and that can be your return type.

After the call of the method, you can find the specific type of the returned object with instanceof;

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called the [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Assuming you are crating `Widgets` I suggest;

- Introduce a `Widget` interface and have `A` and `B` implement `Widget` as per Christopher’s answer
- Rename `ClassSelector` to `WidgetFactory`
- Rename the method `getClassByName` to `create`, make it non-static and return `Widget` instances

This is more aligned with common Java name conventions and thus makes your code readily understandable by most developers.

If you want to keep your factory static it is of course possible but it may make your code less testable as it cannot be switched out for another factory in your tests. This is problematic if A and B are heavy weight objects that carries a lot of external dependencies that you may want to exclude.

If testability is a concern you may even consider making the factory implement a `WidgetFactory` interface...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please note that for string comparison you have not to use "==" (the problem is in `nameOfClass == "A"` and so on, I say it only for completeness).

I want suggest a solution based on reflection, that maybe could be more concise:

```
public interface IClass {

}

public class A implements IClass {
    private String name = "A";
}

public class B implements IClass {
    private String name = "B";
}

public class ClassSelector {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IClass obj = null;
        try {
            Class c = Class.forName("A");
            obj = (IClass) c.newInstance();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Create object of type " + obj.getClass());
    }

}
```